# Why am I getting extra forward slashes in the div JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, calendar

For some reason I'm getting 8 forward slashes rendered on their own line after the header for my dynamically populated calendar. The basic code for it is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCalendar() {
        var now = new Date();
        var thisMonth = now.getMonth();
        var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
        var month = months[now.getMonth()];
        var thisYear = now.getFullYear();
        var firstDay = new Date(thisYear, thisMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var firstDayOfWeek = firstDay.addDays(-firstDay.getDay()); // get the first date of the 5-week calendar
        var calendar = '<header> <h1 class="month-year">' + month + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + thisYear + '</h1> ';
        calendar += '</header> <table> <tr> <th>Sun</th> <th>Mon</th> <th>Tue</th> <th>Wed</th> <th>Thu</th> <th>Fri</th> <th>Sat</th> </tr> ';
        var calMonth = new Array(6); // least amount that will contain an entire month every time
        calMonth[0] = new Array(7); // each week contains 7 days
        calMonth[1] = new Array(7);
        calMonth[2] = new Array(7);
        calMonth[3] = new Array(7);
        calMonth[4] = new Array(7);
        calMonth[5] = new Array(7);
        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                calMonth[i][j] = new Date(firstDayOfWeek); // input each date for the calendar into the array
                firstDayOfWeek = new Date(firstDayOfWeek.addDays(1));
            }
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            calendar += '<tr>';
            for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            var currDate = new Date(calMonth[i][j]);
            day = currDate.getDate();
                if(day == now.getDate() && currDate.getMonth() == now.getMonth()) {
                    calendar += '<td class="moderate current-day">' + day + '</td>';
                } else if(currDate < now) {
                    calendar += '<td class="event heavy"><s>' + day + '</s></td>';
                } else if(currDate.getDay() >= 5) {
                    calendar += '<td class="light">' + day + '</td>/';
                } else if(currDate.getMonth() > now.getMonth() && currDate.getYear() == now.getYear()
                    || currDate.getMonth() < now.getMonth() && currDate.getYear() < now.getYear()) {
                    calendar += '<td class="event moderate next-month">' + day + '</td>';
                } else if(currDate.getMonth() < now.getMonth() && currDate.getYear() == now.getYear()
                    || currDate.getMonth() > now.getMonth() && currDate.getYear() > now.getYear()) {
                    calendar += '<td class="event heavy prev-month">' + day + '</td>';
                } else { calendar += '<td class="event light">' + day + '</td>'; }
            }
            calendar += '</tr>';
        }
        document.getElementById('calendar').innerHTML = calendar;
    }

    Date.prototype.addDays = function (n) {
        var time = this.getTime();
        var changedDate = new Date(time + (n * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        this.setTime(changedDate.getTime());
        return this;
}
</script>
```

When it renders to the `<div class='calendar' id='calendar'></div>`, for some reason it populates `////////` on the line directly below the header, which currently renders `August 2015`.

I don't have anything between the header and the body of the table and I also do not have anything in the actual div until the calendar is rendered (which is during the onload event). An image of it is rendered below:

[image]

Additionally, an in-progress version with current styling can be viewed at [this website](http://homeartsconsulting.com/pages/services.html).

Can anyone help me solve this mystery?

Thanks,

-C§

Comment: There is an extra slash at the end of the line `else if(currDate.getDay() >= 5) { calendar += '<td class="light">' + day + '</td>/';`

Comment: Since the problem was just a typo, and the question is unlikely to be of interest to future readers, feel free to delete it.

Comment: Thanks, @m69. Sometimes when you've seen it a million times you can't see the stupid mistakes that might be obvious to someone else. I'll flag for removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a stray forward slash inside your for loop after the  tag.  It is removed below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCalendar() {
    var now = new Date();
    var thisMonth = now.getMonth();
    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
    var month = months[now.getMonth()];
    var thisYear = now.getFullYear();
    var firstDay = new Date(thisYear, thisMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var firstDayOfWeek = firstDay.addDays(-firstDay.getDay()); // get the first date of the 5-week calendar
    var calendar = '<header> <h1 class="month-year">' + month + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + thisYear + '</h1> ';
    calendar += '</header> <table> <tr> <th>Sun</th> <th>Mon</th> <th>Tue</th> <th>Wed</th> <th>Thu</th> <th>Fri</th> <th>Sat</th> </tr> ';
    var calMonth = new Array(6); // least amount that will contain an entire month every time
    calMonth[0] = new Array(7); // each week contains 7 days
    calMonth[1] = new Array(7);
    calMonth[2] = new Array(7);
    calMonth[3] = new Array(7);
    calMonth[4] = new Array(7);
    calMonth[5] = new Array(7);
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            calMonth[i][j] = new Date(firstDayOfWeek); // input each date for the calendar into the array
            firstDayOfWeek = new Date(firstDayOfWeek.addDays(1));
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        calendar += '<tr>';
        for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        var currDate = new Date(calMonth[i][j]);
        day = currDate.getDate();
            if(day == now.getDate() && currDate.getMonth() == now.getMonth()) {
                calendar += '<td class="moderate current-day">' + day + '</td>';
            } else if(currDate < now) {
                calendar += '<td class="event heavy"><s>' + day + '</s></td>';
            } else if(currDate.getDay() >= 5) {
                calendar += '<td class="light">' + day + '</td>';
            } else if(currDate.getMonth() > now.getMonth() && currDate.getYear() == now.getYear()
                || currDate.getMonth() < now.getMonth() && currDate.getYear() < now.getYear()) {
                calendar += '<td class="event moderate next-month">' + day + '</td>';
            } else if(currDate.getMonth() < now.getMonth() && currDate.getYear() == now.getYear()
                || currDate.getMonth() > now.getMonth() && currDate.getYear() > now.getYear()) {
                calendar += '<td class="event heavy prev-month">' + day + '</td>';
            } else { calendar += '<td class="event light">' + day + '</td>'; }
        }
        calendar += '</tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById('calendar').innerHTML = calendar;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function (n) {
    var time = this.getTime();
    var changedDate = new Date(time + (n * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    this.setTime(changedDate.getTime());
    return this;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Answers that provide a large block of code with ZERO explanation are rarely considered great answers because they require detective work for anyone to know what you actually changed or fixed and why.  Please add an explanation for what you changed and why.

Comment: *rogue - a dishonest or unprincipled man.
"you are a rogue and an embezzler"
rouge - a red powder or cream used as a cosmetic for coloring the cheeks or lips.